# TSQL syntax for updating with inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to convert this mysql query to run on SQL but having some issues with the syntax on join. Basically what I want to do is set the DWH_HISTO to 1 on duplicate rows based on the DWH_DATE. So the older duplicates should be marked.

This is what I've tried

```
UPDATE MAG_L_D3.dbo.INSCRIPT
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(DWH_DATE) as lastId, CODINS
  FROM INSCRIPT
  WHERE DWH_HISTO=0
  GROUP BY CODINS
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.CODINS = MAG_L_D3.dbo.INSCRIPT.CODINS
  SET DWH_HISTO = 1
  WHERE MAG_L_D3.dbo.INSCRIPT.DWH_DATE < duplic.lastId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update using inner join:

```
UPDATE I 
SET DWH_HISTO = 1 FROM MAG_L_D3.dbo.INSCRIPT I
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(DWH_DATE) as lastId, CODINS
  FROM INSCRIPT
  WHERE DWH_HISTO=0
  GROUP BY CODINS
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.CODINS = I.CODINS
  WHERE I.DWH_DATE < duplic.lastId
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by CODINS order by DWH_DATE desc)rn
)
UPDATE CTE
SET DWH_HISTO = 1 
WHERE 
  rn > 1
  and DWH_HISTO=0
```

Comment: wow interesting syntax :O not sure exactly what is going on but will study it :D Thank you

Comment: @C.Astraea it is faster than the join method